# Avoid repeating a function in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to use `dbo.ret_udfCalculateDynamicReportHybridColumn` function in the `WHERE` clause but I have to avoid repeat the function in both `SELECT` and `WHERE` clause, how to get rid of problem?

Here's my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ret_FinancialVoucherArticles_GetArticles]
    (@CalculationGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
     @FinancialVoucherTypeGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
AS
    SELECT
        salaried.CostCenterGuid AS CostCenterEntityGuid,
        salaried.CostCenterCode,
        salaried.PersonGuid AS PersonEntityGuid,
        salaried.PersonCode,
        salaried.[Guid] AS SalariedEntityGuid,
        salaried.FinancialIdentifierCode,
        financial_VoucherArticleTemplates.ArticleNature,
        financial_VoucherArticleTemplates.[Description],
        financial_VoucherArticleTemplates.AccountCodePatternGuid,
        financial_VoucherArticleTemplates.AccountCodePattern,
        financial_VoucherTemplates.TargetDBGuid,
        financial_VoucherTemplates.FiscalYear,
        financial_VoucherTemplates.GroupingIdenticalArticle,
        calcs.[Guid] AS CalculationGuid,
        dbo.ret_udfCalculateDynamicReportHybridColumn(financial_VoucherArticleTemplates.ReferenceGuid) AS Amount
    FROM 
        [ret_payrollCalculations] calcs 
    INNER JOIN 
        [ret_PayrollCalculationInfo] info ON info.PayrollCalculationGuid = calcs.[Guid] 
    INNER JOIN 
        [ret_PayrollCalculationCommands] commands ON commands.[Guid] = calcs.[CalculationCommandGuid] 
    INNER JOIN 
        [ret_PayrollItemPatterns] patterns ON patterns.[Guid] = commands.[ItemPattern] 
    INNER JOIN 
        [ret_FinancialVoucherTemplateGroups] financialVoucherTemplateGroups ON financialVoucherTemplateGroups.[Guid] = patterns.[FinancialVoucherTemplateGroupGuid] 
    INNER JOIN 
        [ret_FinancialVoucherTemplateGroupsDetails] financialVoucherTemplateGroupsDetails ON financialVoucherTemplateGroupsDetails.[FinancialVoucherTemplateGroupGuid] = financialVoucherTemplateGroups.[Guid] AND financialVoucherTemplateGroupsDetails.[FinancialVoucherTypeGuid] = @FinancialVoucherTypeGuid 
    INNER JOIN 
        [gtw_Financial_VoucherTemplates] financial_VoucherTemplates ON financial_VoucherTemplates.[Guid] = financialVoucherTemplateGroupsDetails.[FinancialVoucherTemplateGuid] 
    INNER JOIN
        [gtw_Financial_VoucherArticleTemplates] financial_VoucherArticleTemplates ON financial_VoucherArticleTemplates.[VoucherTemplateGuid] = financial_VoucherTemplates.[Guid] 
    INNER JOIN 
        [ret_vwSalariedFull] salaried ON salaried.[Guid] = calcs.[SalariedGuid]
    WHERE
        calcs.[Guid] = @CalculationGuid 
        AND dbo.ret_udfCalculateDynamicReportHybridColumn(financial_VoucherArticleTemplates.ReferenceGuid) <> 0
```

Comment: If you need to shoe the result from this function and wants to filter some rows, You must have it both the places.

Comment: I assume you want to remove two calls as its expensive?  (assuming you know that SQL is actually calling it twice) Then maybe you could stage it?  Calculate it into a temp table/var first then use it.   That's not to say it will be faster that way, you'd have to measure/time both.

Comment: Why? Is there a misconception that it's calling twice? it might not be.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I think because function execute in where clause first, query optimizer save the result in a variable and use it for the SELECT part.

Comment: Never make assumptions. The query plan should give you some idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a CTE or subquery to compute it once and reference the resulting column as a `WHERE` filter and as a `SELECT` result column:

```
;WITH Data AS
(
    SELECT
        salaried.CostCenterGuid AS CostCenterEntityGuid,
        salaried.CostCenterCode,
        salaried.PersonGuid AS PersonEntityGuid,
        salaried.PersonCode,
        salaried.[Guid] AS SalariedEntityGuid,
        salaried.FinancialIdentifierCode,
        financial_VoucherArticleTemplates.ArticleNature,
        financial_VoucherArticleTemplates.[Description],
        financial_VoucherArticleTemplates.AccountCodePatternGuid,
        financial_VoucherArticleTemplates.AccountCodePattern,
        financial_VoucherTemplates.TargetDBGuid,
        financial_VoucherTemplates.FiscalYear,
        financial_VoucherTemplates.GroupingIdenticalArticle,
        calcs.[Guid] AS CalculationGuid,
        dbo.ret_udfCalculateDynamicReportHybridColumn(financial_VoucherArticleTemplates.ReferenceGuid) AS Amount
    FROM 
        [ret_payrollCalculations] calcs INNER JOIN 
        [ret_PayrollCalculationInfo] info ON info.PayrollCalculationGuid = calcs.[Guid] INNER JOIN 
        [ret_PayrollCalculationCommands] commands ON commands.[Guid] = calcs.[CalculationCommandGuid] INNER JOIN 
        [ret_PayrollItemPatterns] patterns ON patterns.[Guid] = commands.[ItemPattern] INNER JOIN 
        [ret_FinancialVoucherTemplateGroups] financialVoucherTemplateGroups ON financialVoucherTemplateGroups.[Guid] = patterns.[FinancialVoucherTemplateGroupGuid] INNER JOIN 
        [ret_FinancialVoucherTemplateGroupsDetails] financialVoucherTemplateGroupsDetails ON financialVoucherTemplateGroupsDetails.[FinancialVoucherTemplateGroupGuid] = financialVoucherTemplateGroups.[Guid] AND financialVoucherTemplateGroupsDetails.[FinancialVoucherTypeGuid] = @FinancialVoucherTypeGuid INNER JOIN 
        [gtw_Financial_VoucherTemplates] financial_VoucherTemplates ON financial_VoucherTemplates.[Guid] = financialVoucherTemplateGroupsDetails.[FinancialVoucherTemplateGuid] INNER JOIN
        [gtw_Financial_VoucherArticleTemplates] financial_VoucherArticleTemplates ON financial_VoucherArticleTemplates.[VoucherTemplateGuid] = financial_VoucherTemplates.[Guid] INNER JOIN 
        [ret_vwSalariedFull] salaried ON salaried.[Guid] = calcs.[SalariedGuid]
    WHERE
        calcs.[Guid] = @CalculationGuid
)
SELECT
    D.CostCenterEntityGuid,
    D.CostCenterCode,
    D.PersonEntityGuid,
    D.PersonCode,
    D.SalariedEntityGuid,
    D.FinancialIdentifierCode,
    D.ArticleNature,
    D.Description,
    D.AccountCodePatternGuid,
    D.AccountCodePattern,
    D.TargetDBGuid,
    D.FiscalYear,
    D.GroupingIdenticalArticle,
    D.CalculationGuid,
    D.Amount
FROM
    Data AS D
WHERE
    D.Amount <> 0
```

Make sure to check the execution plan to see if it's only being computed once.

Comment: In summary, the OP doens't know whether this is being called twice in the original query. It's just an assumption.